# Cutting hair for donation on Chol Hammoed

Tags: halacha, chol-hamoed, haircuts

Is one allowed to cut their hair on chol hammoed for a mitzvah, more specifically to donate their hair, not for the purpose of a haircut but just making a braid and cutting that braid off the head not an actual haircut?

Comment: highly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20509/8775.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Tzorekh haMoed or a Davar haAveid or Okhel Nefesh. Why should it be permitted?

Comment: If you want to sell the hairs and need the money for the Moved itself, I think that yes.But may be a problem of mar'it haayin because of the great similarity with standard hair cutting